# Search for special characters using grep

Tags: grep, string, search, file-search

I want to search for the lines that contains any of the following characters:

`:` `/` `/` `?` `#` `[` `]` `@` `!` `$` `&` `'` `(` `)` `*` `+` `,` `;` `=` `%`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
grep "[]:/?#@\!\$&'()*+,;=%[]"
```

Within a bracketed expression, `[...]`, very few character are "special" (only a very small subset, like `]`, `-` and `^`, and the three combinations `[=`, `[:` and `[.`).  When including `]` in `[...]`, the `]` must come first (possibly after a `^`). I opted to put the `]` first and the `[` last for symmetry.

The only other thing to remember is that a single quoted string can not include a single quote, so we use double quotes around the expression.  Since we use a double quoted string, the shell will poke around in it for things to expand.  For this reason, we escape the `$` as `\$` which will make the shell give a literal `$` to `grep`, and we escape `!` as `\!` too as it's a history expansion in `bash` (only in interactive `bash` shells though).

Would you want to include a backslash in the set, you would have to escape it as `\\` so that the shell gives a single backslash to `grep`. Also, if you want to include a backtick `` ` ``, it too must be escaped as `` \` `` as it starts a command substitution otherwise.

The command above would extract any line that contained at least one of the characters in the bracketed expression.

---

Using a single quoted string instead of a double quoted string, which gets around most of the annoyances with what characters the  shell interprets:

```
grep '[]:/?#@!$&'"'"'()*+,;=%[]'
```

Here, the only thing to remember, apart from the placing of the `]`, is that a single quoted string can not include a single quote, so instead we use a concatenation of three strings:

1. `'[]:/?#@!$&'`
2. `"'"`
3. `'()*+,;=%[]'`

---

Another approach would be to use the POSIX character class `[[:punct:]]`.  This matches a single character from the set `` !"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~ ``, which is a *larger* set than what's given in the question (it additionally contains `` "-.<>^_`{|}~ ``), but is all the "punctuation characters" that POSIX defines.

```
LC_ALL=C grep '[[:punct:]]'
```

Comment: @ilkkachu I didn't spot the `$` in there! Thanks!

Comment: When I try to execute the command, I get this error `bash: !\: event not found`.

Comment: @user9371654 Darn `bash`! :-)  Escape the `!` too... Not being a `bash` user I forgot about that. I will update...

Comment: @ilkkachu No, you can't put a single quote in a single quoted string like that. you would have to use `'...'"'"'...'`. I will make a note about it.

Comment: @ilkkachu Ah, I see. I opted for a double-quoted `'` instead.

Comment: `"[\!]"` expands to `[\!]` even when history expansion is enabled, so would match on backslash. You'd need single quotes or using `\!` outside of quotes.

Comment: Note that it's not only `bash`, `zsh` also has that annoying feature inherited from csh. in csh, `!` special inside `'...'` as well, and also when non-interactive. However in `csh`  (contrary to bash or zsh), using `"\!"` would work here (the backslash is removed).

Comment: I was using `cpdf` to add bookmarks and getting a `Bad bookmark file (syntax) at line 0` error. This post helped me find the bad chars. (Hopefully this comment helps this post get picked up in search for others with this problem).

Answer (score 6):

You can use `[:punct:]` character class if you don't mind that it also matches other punctuation and special characters:

```
grep '[[:punct:]]' file
```

Comment: The `punct` character class (not macro) matches `!"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~` in the C locale, which is a slightly larges set of characters than what the user has, but it may be good enough.

Answer (score 4):

You can use full regex to find special characters inside of square brackets if your looking for one character that is a special character. A great resource practicing, learning and checking your Regular Expression is [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/).

This uses Perl regular expressions, which can be used with GNU grep with the `-P` option:

```
grep -P "(\:|\/|\?|\#|\@|\!|\\$|\&|\'|\(|\)|\*|\+|\,|\;|\=|\%|\[|\])"
                            ^^^
```

Note that you need *two* backslashes in front of the dollar sign, as it has a special meaning in the shell, and the first backslash will escape it for the shell. <sup>(With just one backslash in front, the shell would remove the backslash, `grep` would see an unescaped dollar sign meaning end of line, and match any input line.)</sup>

If your terminal supports colors, throw colors on as well,

```
grep --color=auto -P "(\:|\/|\?|\#|\@|\!|\\$|\&|\'|\(|\)|\*|\+|\,|\;|\=|\%|\[|\])"
```

Here is the explanation of my regex from [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/)

> ```
> /(\:|\/|\?|\#|\@|\!|\$|\&|\'|\(|\)|\*|\+|\,|\;|\=|\%|\[|\])/gm
> 1st Capturing Group (\:|\/|\?|\#|\@|\!|\$|\&|\'|\(|\)|\*|\+|\,|\;|\=|\%|\[|\])
>   \: matches the character : literally (case sensitive)
>   \/ matches the character / literally (case sensitive)
>   \? matches the character ? literally (case sensitive)
>   \# matches the character # literally (case sensitive)
>   \@ matches the character @ literally (case sensitive)
>   \! matches the character ! literally (case sensitive)
>   \$ matches the character $ literally (case sensitive)
>   \& matches the character & literally (case sensitive)
>   \' matches the character ' literally (case sensitive)
>   \( matches the character ( literally (case sensitive)
>   \) matches the character ) literally (case sensitive)
>   \* matches the character * literally (case sensitive)
>   \+ matches the character + literally (case sensitive)
>   \, matches the character , literally (case sensitive)
>   \; matches the character ; literally (case sensitive)
>   \= matches the character = literally (case sensitive)
>   \% matches the character % literally (case sensitive)
>   \[ matches the character [ literally (case sensitive)
>   \] matches the character ] literally (case sensitive)
> ```

Comment: No, with standard ERE, you can't escape the closing `]` with backslash. backslash is not special inside bracket expressions. To have a `]` inside a bracket expression, it needs to be first: `[]other]`, not  `[ot\]her]`. That's different from PCREs which regex101 describe by default.

Comment: It would work with `pcregrep` or GNU `grep -P`, though. And in a sense, the Perl behaviour is more straightforward: a backslash always makes a special character normal.

Comment: Corrected to -P, sorry about that, i get the -E and -P mixed up